# How to use selection sort with comparator in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, selection, comparator, selection-sort

help here will be greatly appreciated. I'm pretty stuck. What I have to do is I have to use the selection sort algorithm to sort an arraylist, but there are multiple indexes in each object in the arraylist. This has to be done in java.

For example:

```
public class a {

    private int number;
    private String letter;

    public a(int n, String l)
    {
        number = n;
        letter = l;
    }
}

public class SortingArrays {

    private ArrayList<a> myarray;

    private Comparator<a> sortByNumber;
    private Comparator<a> sortByLetter;

    public FootballPlayerData() {

        myarray = new ArrayList<a>();

        getmyarray().add(new a(2, "A"));
        getmyarray().add(new a(7, "J"));

        //COMPARATORs//
        sortByNumber = new Comparator<a>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(a o1, a o2) 
            {
                if (o1.number < (o2.number)) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (o1.number == (o2.number)) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return 1;
            }

        };
        sortByLetter = new Comparator<a>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(a o1, a o2) 
            {
                return o1.letter.compareTo(o2.letter);
            }

         };

    public void selectionSortbyNumber
    {
        ???
    }
    public void selectionSortbyLetter
    {
        ???
    }
}
```

So how do I create a selection sort in java (has to be selection sort) that sorts the arraylist by different elements within the objects? I already have the comparator part down, but I don't know how to incorporate that with selection sort.

Comment: Find a selection sort algorithm on the net, and implement it in Java.

Comment: `Collections.sort` leverages `Arrays.sort` behind the scenes, which uses TimSort (and not selection sort). If you need a specific algorithm, chances are you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: @Mena I've already used collections.sort, but for this assignment I am only allowed to use selection sort unfortunately.

Comment: @coder5777 Are you required to use a `Comparator`? Selection sort may be difficult using a `Comparator` because the scope of a selection sort is wider than just a comparison between two values (as performed by `Comparator`).

Comment: @JustinAlbano, there is absolutely zero problems with implementing any sort algorithm with using a Comparator.

Comment: Hi @coder5777, I think the best way to path your solution would be to start at how the query will be formatted. Can you provide an example of what input will trigger the sort? Does each property of an object have an associated tag or title that can be used to help your algorithm pick the field to sort by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Comparator` implementation is usually used to compare two elements with one another, returning `-1` (or any negative number) if the first element is less than the second, `0` if they are equal, and `1` (or any positive number) if the first element is greater than the second. This can be used to compare two elements to see if one is greater, less than, or equal to the other.

In the context of selection sort, you can use a supplied comparator to determine which value in the unsorted portion of the list is the minimum. The general algorithm for selection sort is as follows:

```
for i from 0 to array.length:
    current_minimum_index = i
    for j from i + 1 to array.length:
        if array at j is less than array at current_minimum_index:
            current_minimum_index = j

        swap array at current_minimum_index with array at i
```

The `if array at j is less than array at current_minimum_index` can be implemented using `Comparator`. For example, given a supplied `ArrayList` called `array`, the call to the `Comparator` object named `comparator` would be:

```
if (comparator.compare(array.get(j), array.get(current_minimum_index))) < 0)
```

I do not want to provide you with the complete answer, as that would not help you learn selection sorting, but the method signature for your sorting would resemble the following:

```
public <T> void selectionSort(ArrayList<T> array, Comparator<T> comparator) {

    // for i from 0 to array.size():
        // currentMinIndex = i
        // for j from i + 1 to array.size():
            if (comparator.compare(array.get(j), array.get(currentMinIndex))) < 0) {
                // currentMinIndex = j
            }

            // swap array at currentMinIndex with array at i
}
```

Your call to this method would then look like one of the following:

```
selectionSort(myarray, sortByNumber);
selectionSort(myarray, sortByLetter);
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a question though. When using this, will I still need my original comparator methods, or will I not need them since the comparator will be fully implemented into the selection sort?

Comment: You still use your `Comparator` objects: You pass them into the `selectionSort` method. The logic in those `Comparator` implementations determines if one value is less than another during the selection sort.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out. This was just what I needed :)

Comment: @coder5777: You're welcome. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Source from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort:

```
/* a[0] to a[n-1] is the array to sort */
int i,j;
int n;

/* advance the position through the entire array */
/*   (could do j < n-1 because single element is also min element) */
int iMin;
for (j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
    /* find the min element in the unsorted a[j .. n-1] */
    /* assume the min is the first element */
    iMin = j;
    /* test against elements after j to find the smallest */
    for (i = j+1; i < n; i++) {
        /* if this element is less, then it is the new minimum */
        if (a[i] < a[iMin]) {
            /* found new minimum; remember its index */
            iMin = i;
        }
    }
}

if (iMin != j) {
    swap(a[j], a[iMin]);
}
```

The method `swap()` just switch the values in the array.

Your job will be to swap the array with list. :P But that's not so hard because you can access the list value by index `get(int index)` method.